# Exporting NativeScript UI Chart data

Tags: image, charts, export, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am trying to extract/export a UI Chart as image data (jpg).  Ultimately I want to get the image data directly:

image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...encodedContent...'

Is it possible or can it be combined with another NativeScript plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [nativescript-screenshot](https://github.com/enchev/nativescript-screenshot) plugin, it returns a image source which you may write it to a file / convert to base64 string.

Comment: Great suggestion.  Thank you.